# JSError : ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: c#, jquery, gecko

I am using Geckowebbrowser and trying to execute jquery, jquery code already working with chrome inspector, but when I am trying to execute it with Gecko it gives me an error

> JSError : ReferenceError: $ is not defined StackTrace: @:1:1

```
$('input[name="session[username_or_email]"]').val('TheValue'); 
GeckoBrowser.ExecuteJQuery("$('input[name=\"session[username_or_email]\"]').val('Test');");
```

Comment: @Marven Take a [tour] to learn what should you do when someone answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Gecko web browser is just a browser control.

So you just have to import the library just like in every other browser.
For example including a simple `script` tag in the html page you are loading:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```